# Editing a style programmaticaly (when the user changes settings)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Note: I'm not looking to SET a style, I want to dynamically change a style which is declared in styles.xml.

For example, my app has a widget with layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgettext1"
    style="@style/My.WidgetTextView"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgettext2"
    style="@style/My.WidgetTextView"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgettext3"
    style="@style/My.WidgetTextView"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgettext4"
    style="@style/My.WidgetTextView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In styles.xml I have this:

```
<style name="My.WidgetTextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">#99221111</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:enabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/widget_font</item>
</style>
```

Now, I want to allow user to change some visual settings, like text size or background color.

The easiest way seems to be to edit the style somehow, so I don't have to apply it to each textview or something. Is this possible?

Someone could propose creating a bunch of styles and let the user choose between them, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can set style e.g. `My.WidgetTextView` programmatically using:

```
ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(Context, R.style.My.WidgetTextView);

TextView myText = new TextView(context);
```

However you can not change the attributes of `My.WidgetTextView` programmatically.

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with my question.

Comment: Ok I modified my answer, hope this help.

Comment: This is a bit closer, but still, how do I edit the style itself dynamically? I don't want just the style that I create in the xml file.